# A member pointer of a class gets garbaged when data is copied to another member of class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Here is the problem I have now:

```
class Header{

   //something here

};

class Packet{

    public:

        Packet(Header* _header){
           header = _header;
        };

        char buf[1000];

        Header* header;
}
```

So it looks that simple. When i create a Header (_header), and then use it as an argument to create a Packet, everything looks good in debugger: the pointer header of packet does point to the _header created earlier.

Now, I start loading 1000 characters to buf. For the first few hundreds of chars, thing still looks good. But when the number of chars copied to buf gets bigger (around 800), then the pointer header of packet suddenly gets garbaged. Have no idea why. Later when I try to access header of the created packet, it's a garbaged address and the program crashed.

I tried 2 ways of loading the buf (by `strcpy` and copying one by one, like `buf[i]=...`), but still face the same problem.

Can any help clarify or fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Whatever `_header` is pointing to probably went out of scope.

Comment: Barmar, how did you edit the code? I was struggling while trying to format it.

Comment: @Simo I just added spaces. Watch out for TAB characters, they don't format properly.

Comment: Show us the code that's creating the objects and filling in `buf`. Please indent it properly (with space characters, no TABs) and use the `{}` tool in the SO editor to display it as code.

Comment: Why don't you use a `string` instead of a char array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the problem of going beyond the array bounds by swapping the definitions of header and buf in the class.  Change it to

```
Header* header;
char buf[1000];
```

and the overrun of buf into header will not be a problem.  You will still have to figure out the issue with buffer overrun.

Comment: This will just overflow into something else, it's not really a solution.

Comment: Indeed. I swapped the positions, and the problem is gone. And now I found out I did write more than 1000 chars to buf. Silly me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This problem means you're writing to `buf` beyond its bounds. Make sure you never write beyond the 1000th index and you'll be fine.

Comment: he said the problem happens when he gets to about 800.

Comment: @Barmar That's true, but can you think of any other reason for it to only happen when he gets to a larger number? We need more code to be entirely sure

Comment: I agree, that's why I posted a comment asking him to show the relevant code.

Comment: Sorry I was so wrong. I thought 800, but it was more than 1000. Beat me if you can :)

Comment: @Simo Don't forget to accept unxnut's answer to make sure everyone sees what solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing in Header* _header, the data at the location you are storing inside of the class Packet is not managed by the class.  Should something happen to whoever allocated this memory, it would be reflected in the reference to it in the Packet class.
Where is the code that initializes the value that is passed into the Packet constructor?  I imagine that your issue is there.  Is it on the stack?  Do you call new?  I bet it is a stack variable you are passing into the constructor.